# Laravel: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::create_table ()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning Laravel and migrating a database table with

php artisan migrate

then I get an error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::create_table()
```

Where does it come from?

Here is the code of the migration:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTodoTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::create('todos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('text');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
    Schema::dropIfExists('todos');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel doesn't have `create_table` method. This means you've tried to use this name somewhere instead of using `create`.

So, search for `create_table`, change it to `create`. Then run `composer du` and `php artisan migrate` commands.

Comment: Yeah, I used the name create_table but renamed it into create. The error persists after command du (which is reset I suppose). There is a function create_table in RegisterController.php though but it is part of the orginal create user migration.

Comment: @puolimatkankrouvi then fix it in the `RegisterController` too. If you can't do that, please show this controller.

Comment: Ok! I did find and replace create_table -> create and it changed them everywhere and now it works.